# Sending E-Mail to various recipients with Python

Tags: python, email

I want to send an email to various recipients (like 10 people) with the given table in the code, but the mail only reaches the first mail address. Is there a way to code it the way, that I can send an email to various recipients?

```
df = pd.DataFrame(Table)

filename = str(date.today()) + ".png"

#dir = pathlib.Path(__file__).parent.absolute()

folder = r"/results/"

#path_plot = str(dir) + folder + filename

from_mail = "abcdef@gmail.com"
to_mail = 'example1@hotmail.com,example2@live.com, example2@yahoo.com, example2@yahoo.de'
smtp_server = "smtp.gmail.com"
smtp_port = 465
def send_email( smtp_server, smtp_port, from_mail, from_password, to_mail):
    '''
        Send results
    '''
 
    msg = MIMEMultipart()
    msg['Subject'] = 'Results'
    msg['From'] = from_mail
    COMMASPACE = ', '
    msg['To'] = COMMASPACE.join([from_mail, to_mail])
    msg.preamble = 'Something special'
    
    html = """\
    <html>
    <head></head>
    <body>
    {0}
    </body>
    </html>
    """.format(df.to_html())
    part1 = MIMEText(html, 'html')
    msg.attach(part1)
```

Comment: `to_mail` should be a *list* of addresses, not a comma-separated string, and then `COMMASPACE.join([from_mail, *to_mail])` should produce a correctly concatenated list.

Comment: I reverted your recent edit, as it just obscured a minor detail without really improving anything substantial.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `to_addr` argument should be a list of strings if you want to send to multiple recipients.

The immediate problem in your code is that you are joining the `from_addr` with the (string or list) `to_addr` where you should be creating a single list to put in the recipients field.

As an aside, your code seems to be written for Python 3.5 or earlier. The `email` library was overhauled in 3.6 and is now quite a bit more versatile and logical. Probably throw away what you have and start over with the [examples from the `email` documentation.](https://docs.python.org/3/library/email.examples.html)
Here is a basic refactoring (just quick and dirty; the structure is rather weird - why are you passing some strings as parameters whereas others are globals outside the function?). It removes some of the problems in your code simply because the modern API removes a lot of the boilerplate which was necessary with the older one.

```
import pandas as pd # I'm guessing ...?
from email.message import EmailMessage

...
df = pd.DataFrame(Table)

# Commenting out unused variables
# filename = str(date.today()) + ".png"
# folder = "/results/"  # no need for an r string, no backslashes here

from_mail = "abcdef@gmail.com"
from_password = cred.passwort 
to_mail = ['example1@hotmail.com', 'example2@live.com', 'example2@yahoo.com', 'example2@yahoo.de']

smtp_server = "smtp.gmail.com"
smtp_port = 465

def send_email(smtp_server, smtp_port, from_mail, from_password, to_mail):
    '''
        Send results via mail
    '''
 
    msg = EmailMessage()
    msg['Subject'] = 'Results'
    msg['From'] = from_mail
    msg['To'] = ', '.join(to_mail + [from_mail])
    # Don't muck with the preamble, especially if you don't understand what it is
    
    html = """\
    <html>
    <head></head>
    <body>
    {0}
    </body>
    </html>
    """.format(df.to_html())
    msg.set_content(html, 'html')
    
    with smtplib.SMTP_SSL(smtp_server, smtp_port) as server:
        server.ehlo()
        server.login(from_mail, from_password)
        # Some servers require a second ehlo() here

        # Use send_message instead of legacy sendmail method
        server.send_message(msg)
        server.quit()

send_email(smtp_server, smtp_port, from_mail, from_password, to_mail)
```

The generated HTML is still hideous but let's just hope nobody looks at the message source.

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
    send_email(smtp_server, smtp_port, from_mail, from_password, to_mail)
    message.set_contents(html, 'html')
AttributeError: module 'email.message' has no attribute 'set_contents'

Comment: Another typo fixed; sorry again. It would help if your attempt were a [mre] so that we would not have to guess so many things about the variables etc you are using but not declaring, and the mystery `pd` could probably be factored out if it's not central to your question.

Comment: Thanks a lot, can I ask you something more? Did you see the HTML in the mail? Is there a possibility to make the URL clickable in and get it visually a bit designed?

Comment: The basic syntax for putting a hyperlink in HTML is `<a href="http://example.com/path/to/page">link text</a>` where beginners like to put "click here" in the link text, and more experienced users put something actually useful, such as perhaps the URL itself once more so that viewers can see what they are about to click on. Probably post a new question if you can't figure it out; but probably before that, review the [help] and in particular [How to ask](/help/how-to-ask), and search for existing questions before asking.

Comment: It's not clear what you mean by "visually a bit designed" but I guess you want to add some CSS styling. Again, probably review an introduction to HTML.